# Reading Multiple files and writing to one file Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently trying to make a data pipeline using Node.js
Of course, it's not the best way to make it but I want to try implementing it anyways before I make improvements upon it.

This is the situation

I have multiple gzip compressed csv files on AWS S3. I get these "objects" using aws sdk

like the following and make them into readStream

```js
const unzip = createGunzip()
const input = s3.getObject(parameterWithBucketandKey)
.createReadStream()
.pipe(unzip)
```

and using the stream above I create readline interface

```js
const targetFile = createWriteSTream('path to target file');
const rl = createInterface({
input: input
})
let first = true;
rl.on('line', (line) => {
   if(first) {
     first = false;
     return;
  }
   targetFile.write(line);
   await getstats_and_fetch_filesize();
   if(filesize > allowed_size){
      changed_file_name = change_the_name_of_file()
      compress(change_file_name)
   }
});
```

and this is wrapped as a promise

and I have array of filenames to be retrieved from AWS S3 and map those array of filenames like this

```js
const arrayOfFileNames = [name1, name2, name3 ... and 5000 more]
const arrayOfPromiseFileProcesses= arrayOfFileNames.map((filename) => return promiseFileProcess(filename))

await Promise.all(arrayOfPromiseFileProcesses);


// the result should be multiple gzip files that are compressed again.
```

sorry I wrote in pseudocode if it needs more to provide context then I will write more but I thought this would give a general contenxt of my problem.

My problem is that it writes to a file fine, but when i change the file_name it it doesn't create one afterwards. I am lost in this synchronous and asynchronous world...

Please give me a hint/reference to read upon. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using `return` in arrow functions if the body isn't wrapped in curly braces

Answer (score 0):

line event handler must be a async function as it invokes await

```
rl.on('line', async(line) => {
  if(first) {
    first = false;
    return;
 }
 targetFile.write(line);
 await getstats_and_fetch_filesize();
 if(filesize > allowed_size){
  changed_file_name = change_the_name_of_file()
  compress(change_file_name)
 }
});
```